# FILTER() Is not returning consistent results

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having some issues with FILTER() not returning consistent results, below is an image detailing the inconsistencies.

[image]

When filtering for `3:30 PM` I only get 2 results instead of 3. When filtering for `11:00 PM` I get 4 results out of 4.

Why is this?

Edit: Turns out the numbers are not exactly the same:

[image]

However, the odd part is, those numbers are originally pulled from here:

[image]

This makes all of it even more confusing, whats going on here?

Comment: Figured out where it's coming from, I have a form that is used to submit data on missed times..etc If you submit that form as 3:30 PM the number it submits is `0.645833333335759` and if you type out `3:30 PM` in the spreadsheet, the number it uses is `0.645833333333333`. I need to ask a  new question. It does this with  any time interval.

Answer (score 2):

Timestamps are stored as floating point numbers in double precision, on the scale where 1 corresponds to a day. It is generally advisable not to test floating point numbers for equality; the rounding errors, inevitable in almost any calculation with them, may lead to unexpected results.

It appears that the transmission of time data from  a form to the spreadsheet involved some sort of rounding of binary data along the way. Compare:

- [binary form of 0.645833333333333](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046054052053056051051051051051051051051051051051)
- [binary form of 0.645833333335759](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046054052053056051051051051051051051053055053057)

The number of zeros at the end of mantissa of the second number indicates that it was rounded along the way.

---

One solution is to use fuzzy comparison, for example

```
=filter(A76:A96, abs(A76:A96-B76) < 1e-9)
```

Since 10<sup>-9</sup> days is less than 0.1ms, this matches the timestamps that are indistinguishable for practical purposes.

---

Another solution is to "fix" the distorted timestamp by converting the time to a string and back:

```
=timevalue(text(A92, "hh:mm:ss"))
```

This will return the result identical to other 3:30 PM entries of your sheet.

Comment: I did not consider floating point errors as being applicable in google docs in this form, since you should be able to directly compare two times (which are floats) without error. In this case, the erroneous numbers are being submitted from a google docs form.

How does your function work? the Absolute Value of that would not be less than 0.000000001 and would return false no?

Comment: Absolute value of the _difference_ is less than 1e-9. Two numbers entered directly into a sheet ought to be comparable, but receiving one of them from another source, with associated data format changes, makes comparison less certain.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, and it works! However, is there any way to just "convert" the bad number, to the correct one somewhere along the way? So I'm not fumbling with it throughout the entire spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, I added this at the end of my answer.