# Google Forms submits times that are not numerically consistent with those in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

When I submit a Google Form, and I fill in a time the number that is entered into the spreadsheet is not the same number the spreadsheet will use for that time.

ie. If I enter 3:30 PM in a form and submit it. It enters the number `0.1458333333357590` into the google spreadsheet. If I type out 3:30 PM in the spreadsheet it is represented by: `0.1458333333333330`.

Here is an example Form and Spreadsheet you can see this on. Go to the form, enter a time in the time picker, and enter your time as a string. You can then go to the spreadsheet and see that the submitted time does not equal the actual time the spreadsheet uses.

- [Link to Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1vnBW3-D1fx1uAqRkpyphunkktpg8BJpCNHe_kDVGXow/viewform?usp=send_form)
- [Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JgzlMefwhYcAN2XpIHbRBsTEZzfMPXCWZdHFOJECGrE/edit?usp=sharing)

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? This seems like a docs bug to me...

Related To: [FILTER() Is not returning consistent results](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84927/filter-is-not-returning-consistent-results)

New Question with entirely different premises.

Comment: I don't understand your examples. The spreadsheet shows 3:30 AM and 5:45 AM, different times. Neither of those is 3:30 PM. I just submitted 3rd entry, 3:30PM. It is represented by 0.645833333333333 as it should be (15.5 / 24).

Comment: You answered this question in another question Normal Human! However, on the spreadsheet, when you submit a time and the string of your time I take your submitted time and display the float that it is comprised of, I then take your string and turn that into a time with `TIMEVALUE()` and display the float it is comprised of. So that I can highlight the inconsistencies. `Submitted Time` corelates to `Submitted Time As Number` and `Submitted Text time` corelated to `Submitted Text Time As Number`

Comment: My question was mostly about the inconsistency between writing "3:30 PM"  in this post and quoting numbers such as 0.1458333... which correspond to 3:30 **AM**.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fractional time difference (milliseconds) between the time entered when you enter into the form vs directly into the sheet.  Possibly this is a bug.

I think you can fix it by rounding the values:  check for equality with a formula like

round(time1, 6) = round (time2,6)

Answer (score -2):

You simply need to change the formatting for the column you want the time displayed in. You are seeing the TIMEVALUE() value for the specified time.

Go to **Format** -> **Number** -> **Time** to see it displayed as you desire.

Or go to **Format** -> **Number** -> **More formats** -> **More date and time formats** if you'd like to customize it further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James! That's not the problem sadly. I can format it till I'm blue in the face, but I CANNOT compare the times because they are not the same. `3:30 PM` != `3:30 PM` when their floats are not exactly the same. This prevents me from filtering any of my data based on time (or using `DGET()`, or `QUERY()`)